# Symbolic variable naming issue

Tags: matlab

I have a function that generates a certain number of symbolic variables according to a parameter. This works fine until I choose the parameter to be 1.
Then, instead of `x1` as desired, I get `x11`

I know I could set up an if case, to check if the parameter is 1 then do it separately, but that seems rather ugly.

Here is what I use:

```
X = sym('x%d',[1,parameter]);
```

This gives me a list of variables `x1,x2,...,x(parameter)`

However, when `parameter = 1` I get:
`x11` when I actually need `x1`

I am sure there is an easy fix for this but I am just missing it. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `%d`.

```
X = sym('x', [1,parameter]);
```